# make w0rp Async Lint Engine "ALE" as fast as possible?

Tags: vim, lint

I'm a happy user of the the excellent async linter ALE [w0rp-ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) with Vim.

I'd like to make ALE as fast as possible -- for example, currently when I correct an error, there's about a half second pause for the warning to disappear. Any tips on how I can make that even faster ?

I could open a ticket on the github page, but I'm curious to see who might see this post on SO as well. Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go for `g:ale_lint_delay=0`

From ale doc:

```
g:ale_lint_delay                                             *g:ale_lint_delay*

  Type: |Number|
  Default: `200`

  This variable controls the milliseconds delay after which the linters will
  be run after text is changed. This option is only meaningful with the
  |g:ale_lint_on_text_changed| variable set to `always`, `insert`, or `normal`.
```

One can test time of `:ALELint` and command line version of the linter: (`pylint`). (I may do and post here)